# How can I properly drop an Active Record Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Among my migrations, I have 3 that pertain to this question. In order, there is `CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration`. The next down the line is `CreateYears < ActiveRecord::Migration`. Then the last is `AddYearIdToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration`. The last one looks like this...

```
class AddYearIdToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :year_id, :integer, null: false, index: true
  end
end
```

Now the problem is, whenever I try to drop the entire database (not near deploying to production), I get an obvious error of

```
ERROR:  cannot drop table years because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint events_year_id_fk on table events depends on table seasons
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

Now, I'm not a rails expert, but I believe I need to define a `def down` in that last migration. Rather than def change, do I need a def up and def down? The def down to drop this particular column.

If so, how can I do this. This migration is 20 migrations old. You can't just edit a migration like that can you? Do I add a new migration and just specify a def down? Or is the answer something completely different?

Comment: What command are you using to drop the entire database? `rake db:drop`?

Comment: @dx7 I was using `rake db:reset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried rolling back your migrations? This undoes your migrations in reverse order, i.e. starting with the most recent migration.

```
$ rake db:rollback
```

If you have 20 migrations and you'd like to rollback all of them, you can use `STEP=20`

```
$ rake db:rollback STEP=20
```

Once you rollback past a migration that you'd like to change, you can change it.

In addition, you should be able to use `rake db:drop`, which drops the entire database rather than going through each migration in reverse order. If you'd like to drop the database, then recreate it and re-run all the migrations, you can run `rake db:reset`. Keep in mind this also runs `rake db:seed` if you have a `db/seed.rb` file.

And in response to your question of "Rather than def change, do I need a def up and def down?", the answer is no. Newer versions of Rails use `def change` since (among other reasons) it makes it easier to edit migrations once they are generated, i.e. if you spell a column name incorrectly when adding a column to a table.